# System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException while trying to access a WCF service from a Windows Forms client application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I am new to WCF security and I am trying to access a secured web service hosted on my web-server. I am using Windows Authentication to authenticate WCF requests. Following is the code that I am using on the client application that is developed in Windows Forms:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential creds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Administrator", "mypassword", "mysubdomain.domain.com");
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = false;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = creds;
MessageBox.Show(client.GetData(34));
```

But I am getting following exception even my credentials are correct:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException was unhandled
  Message=The caller was not authenticated by the service.
  Source=WCFTest
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenProvider.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.OpenTokenProviderIfRequired(SecurityTokenProvider tokenProvider, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at WCFTest.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Work\ACA\WCFTest\WCFTest\Form1.cs:line 38
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at WCFTest.Program.Main() in e:\Work\ACA\WCFTest\WCFTest\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.ServiceModel.FaultException
       Message=The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
       Source=System.ServiceModel
       Action=http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault
       StackTrace:
            at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
            at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
       InnerException:
```

And my service uses Windows Authentication. Following is the App.config file of my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="RequestUserName_IService1" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://subdomain.domain.in/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="RequestUserName_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="RequestUserName_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/domain" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Service has wsHttpBindings and is running well and good. So am I missing something in calling it from client side?

Comment: turn on wcf trace on the server to see what exception it contians (search for inner exceptions down the exceptions tree in the right side of trace viewer)

Comment: The log shows `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed` but I am unable to predict its reason.

Comment: Try to play with values of AllowedImpersonationLevel, AllowNtlm (just to focus on what is the issue, you can return it later).

Comment: Nothing happened. Its still showing that exception.

Comment: Maybe your client uses the credentials of the current logged in user and not the one you have set in code for some reason. Does the logged in user has permissions? can you try to put (temporarly) client and server on the same machine? Does server process has admin permissions? Also for now I would try with AllowNtlm=true.

Comment: I tried it on same machine, it was working fine. But when I hosted my service on remote server, above exception showed up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35669/discussion-between-aishwarya-shiva-and-yaron-naveh)

Comment: Now `MessageSecurityException` occured
when I tried to change `AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;`

Comment: what if you put both client and server on the remote server?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong?

Comment: @antiduh Ya I solved it but sorry I can't remember what I actually did at that time to solve this. It was just trial and error method that worked for me. :) After that we actually changed the binding type, so I don't even have that code with me now. If in future I found that solution, I will post it here.